# How can I specify the ABI of my emulator to x86_64 when using Firebase Test Lab?

Tags: android, firebase, gcloud, firebase-test-lab, google-cloud-test-lab

**Background:**
Some people are having [this issue](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/466#issuecomment-743264258) where their UI tests fail when their emulators aren't using ABI x86_64. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems to be a problem when running automated tests via Firebase Test Lab (via [`gcloud firebase test android run`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run)), because their emulators do not seem to be using ABI x86_64.

**When using [`gcloud firebase test android run`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run), is it possible to set the ABI of the emulator being used?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently Firebase Test Lab supports `x86` ABIs on virtual devices, but not `x86_64` yet. However, `x86_64` support is expected to come later this year when Android S devices are released.

Also, the `gcloud firebase test android models describe MODEL_ID` command will list which ABIs each Android device supports.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Regarding "x86_64 support is expected to come later this year when Android S devices are released"... Do you happen to know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: I just checked and the NexusLowRes virtual device now supports x86_64 with abi 31, but only supports up to version 30. The test lab docu still states x86-only support as a limitation for virtual devices: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/avds .

Answer (score 1):

> Android ABIs:
>
> Different Android devices use different CPUs, which in turn support different instruction sets. Each combination of CPU and instruction set has its own Application Binary Interface (ABI). An ABI includes the following information:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis

This is likely intentionally restricted by gcloud so the ABI used associates with the devices being tested. If you want to determine if the ABI is indeed the issue, you can use:

`gcloud firebase test android models list`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/command-line

to see a list of Android devices in gcloud and discover (manually) what ABI they use, and if they are causing you problems.